# Illustrator: how to create a gradient with transparent ends on both sides

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, svg, transparency, borders

I have an image like this
[image]

And i want to add transparent borders like this
[image]

I made the second image with photoshop but i don't know to do this on Illustrator.

i want to make something like this with an image : 
[image]

With transparent borders. Sorry i just start using AI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A gradient with 3 color stops... all the same green, and change the opacity of the end stops...

[image]

When saved to a PNG, the transparency will be in the PNG file... if that's what you are after.

## To use this on an image as in your example....

Place the image in Illustrator and draw a rectangle on top of it. Fill that rectangle with a 3-stop gradient, setting the *middle* stop to have an opacity of 0%...

For the gradient, you'll want to use the "Registration" swatch so it include all colors. Otherwise, you may get some bleed though in the mask due to a color not being fully masked.

Note this is the opposite of the opacity settings shown in the green box above intentionally. Since you will be using this to *hide* elements, not just create transparency, you'll need the opacity to be set up differently.

[image]

Select both the image and the gradient rectangle, and on the **Transparency Panel** click the `Make Mask` button, then tick the `Clip` option so it is *not* ticked. This creates an **Opacity Mask** in Illustrator.

[image]

For more information regarding Opacity Masks, see here: https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/how-to/illustrator-opacity-masks-transparency.html